# Calculate the limit of the following recurrent series

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limit of the series : $\ q_{n+1,}=q_n + \frac{2}{q_n}$ with $q_0=1,n\ge 0$.

Comment: Hint: Any limit $L$ of this sequence would have to satisfy $L^2 = L^2 + 2$, which is absurd unless $L = \infty$, so you could proceed from there.

Comment: @AbhinavVNatarajan could you please explain why this sequence would have to satisfy that condition?

Comment: Multiply the equation through by $q_n$ and take limits on both sides as $n \to \infty$, which you can do if you assume $L$ exists. Therefore $L = \infty$ or the sequence does not have a well defined limit. But the sequence is a monotonically increasing one, so the former must be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us study the sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ with $a_n:=q_n^2$, where $q_n$ is defined in the original question. Squaring the given recurrence relation for $q_n$ yileds

$$q_{n+1}^2=q_n^2+4+\frac{4}{q_n^2}.$$

Using the definition of $a_n$, we get $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{4}{a_n}+4$. From this we obtain for every positive integer $N$ the equality

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left (\frac{4}{a_n}+4\right ).$$

Summing the left-hand side and estimating the right-hand one (we use the obvious fact $a_1\ge 1$) implies the inequality

$$a_N>4N+1,\qquad N\ge 1.$$

Since $q_n=\sqrt{a_n}$, we have $q_N>\sqrt{4N+1}$ for each positive integer $N$. Taking into account that $q_0=1$, we finally state

$$q_n\ge\sqrt{4n+1},\qquad n\in\mathbb N_0.$$

Hence, $q_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

proposition: if $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) < 0,$ then recurrence
$$ q_{n+1} = q_n + f(q_n) $$
is unbounded.

start of proof: suppose we have reached $q_n < M.$ As long as that holds, $f(q_n) > f(M).$ This means that we will have reached or passed $M$ within $$ \frac{M - q_n}{f(M)} $$
additional steps.

So, there is no upper bound, but we can also say that for very small $f,$ it takes longer to pass any given point. The sequence $p_{n+1} = p_n + \frac{1}{e^{p_n}}$ takes a very long time to pass, say, 100.

Comment: I think you mean $f(q_n) > f(M)$.

Comment: @martycohen  thank you

Answer (score 1):

I will show that
$q_n$ is unbounded
and that
$\frac12+\sqrt{2n-\frac74}
\lt q_n
<3+2\sqrt{ 2 n+\frac14}
$.

Moreover,
if,
as these inequalities make plausible,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{q_n}{\sqrt{n}}
$
exists and this limit is $c$,
then $c = 2$,
so that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{q_n}{\sqrt{n}}
=2
$.

Here we go.

$q_n > 1$ for $n > 1$
and $q_n$ is increasing.

If $q_n$ is bounded,
there is an $L$
such that $q_n \le L$
for all $n$.

Writing
$q_{n+1}=q_n + \frac{2}{q_n}
$
as
$q_{n+1}-q_n 
= \frac{2}{q_n}
$
and summing

$\begin{array}\\
q_{n+1}-q_1
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (q_{k+1}-q_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{q_k}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{L}\\
&\ge \dfrac{2n}{L}\\
\end{array}
$

which is unbounded,
a contradiction.

Note that this can be used,
as Will Jagy wrote,
to show that
if
$q_{n+1} = q_n+f(q_n)$
where
$f(x) > 0$
and
$f'(x) < 0$
then
$q_n$ is unbounded.-

This can be used
to get explicit bounds.

$\begin{array}\\
q_{n+1}-q_1
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (q_{k+1}-q_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{q_k}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{q_n}\\
&\ge \dfrac{2n}{q_n}\\
&\gt \dfrac{2n}{q_{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

so,
letting
$\frac{q_1}{2} = a$,

$\begin{array}\\
q_n > \dfrac{2n-2}{q_n}+2a\\
\text{or}\\
q_n^2-2aq_n > 2n-2\\
\text{or}\\
q_n^2-2aq_n+a^2 > 2n-2+a^2\\
\text{or}\\
(q_n-a)^2 > 2n-2+a+a^2\\
\text{or}\\
q_n
\gt a+\sqrt{2n-2+a^2}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$q_n
\gt a+\sqrt{2n-2+a^2}\\
= \frac12+\sqrt{2n-\frac74}\\
$.

With this lower bound for $q_n$,
we can now get an upper bound.

Let $2-a^2 = b$.

$\begin{array}\\
q_{n+1}-q_1
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{q_k}\\
&=\frac{2}{q_1}+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{2}{q_k}\\
&\lt\frac{2}{q_1}+2\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{a+\sqrt{2n-b}}\\
&\lt\frac{2}{q_1}+2\sum_{k=2}^n \int_{k-1}^k\frac{dx}{a+\sqrt{2x-b}}\\
&\lt\frac{2}{q_1}+2\int_{1}^n\frac{dx}{a+\sqrt{2x-b}}\\
&=\frac{2}{q_1}++2(\sqrt{ 2 x-b} - a \log(\sqrt{ 2 x-b} + a))|_{1}^n\\
&=\frac{2}{q_1}+2(\sqrt{2 n-b} - a \log(\sqrt{2 n-b} + a))\\
&\qquad-2(\sqrt{a^2+2}-\log(\sqrt{a^2+2}+a))\\
&=\frac{2}{q_1}+2(\sqrt{a^2 + 2 (n+1)} - a \log(\sqrt{a^2 + 2( n+1)} + a))\\
&\qquad-2(\sqrt{2-b}-\log(\sqrt{2-b}+a))\\
\text{or}\\
q_{n}-q_1
&<\frac{2}{q_1}+2(\sqrt{a^2 + 2n} - a \log(\sqrt{a^2 + 2n} + a))\\
&\qquad-2(\sqrt{a^2+2}-\log(\sqrt{a^2+2}+a))\\
&<\frac{2}{q_1}+2\sqrt{a^2+ 2 n}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$q_n
\lt 2a+\frac{2}{q_1}+2\sqrt{a^2+ 2 n}
= 3+2\sqrt{ 2 n+\frac14}
$.

Assuming a little more,
if
$q_n \approx c\sqrt{n}+O(1)$,
then
$c\sqrt{n+1}-c\sqrt{n}+O(1)
=\dfrac{2}{c\sqrt{n}+O(1)}
=\dfrac{2}{c\sqrt{n}}+O(\dfrac1{n})
$
so, since

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{n+d}}
\qquad 0 \le d \le 1, mvt\\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+d/n}}\\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{n}}(1+O(\dfrac1{n}))\\
\end{array}
$

$\dfrac{c}{2\sqrt{n}}+O(\dfrac1{n^{3/2}})
=\dfrac{2}{c\sqrt{n}}+O(1/n)
$
so
$\dfrac{c}{2}=\dfrac{2}{c}$
so that $c = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Making my comment an answer: since the sequence is monotonically increasing, it is either unbounded (and converges to $\infty$ by definition) or is bounded and has a finite limit. Now $$
q_{n+1} q_n = q_n^2 + 2
$$
which implies that any finite limit $L$ would have to satisfy $L^2 = L^2 + 2$, which is absurd. Hence $q_n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $$x_n>0$$ for all $$n$$ by induction and then use the AM-GM inequalitiy.

Comment: But this only tells us that $$q_{n+1}\ge 2\cdot \sqrt{2}$$ It doesn't provide an upper bound...