# Conjecture on the growth of $q_1 = 1, q_{n+1}=q_n + f(q_n) $

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, conjectures

This is a generalization
of my answer to
[Calculate the limit of the following recurrent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3179916/calculate-the-limit-of-the-following-recurrent-series)
in the form suggested by
Will Jagy.

$q_1 = 1,
 q_{n+1}=q_n + f(q_n)
$
where
$f(x) > 0$
and
$f'(x) < 0$.

I show that
$q_n$ is unbounded
and derive a conjecture
for the growth of
$q_n$
as a function of $f(x)$.

To make my question explicit
(since some people seem to want that):

Is my conjecture 
on the growth of
$q_n$
true?

My conjecture for
$f(x) = \dfrac{a}{x^b}
$
is
$q_n \approx (a(b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)}
$
and for
$f(x) = \dfrac{a}{b^x}
$
is
$q_n \approx \dfrac{\ln(a\ln(b)n)}{\ln(b)}$.

First,
a proof that
$q_n$ is unbounded.

$q_n > 1$ for $n > 1$
and $q_n$ is increasing.

If $q_n$ is bounded,
there is an $L$
such that $q_n \le L$
for all $n$
so that,
since $f'(x) < 0$,
$f(q_n) \ge f(L)$.

Writing
$q_{n+1}=q_n + f(q_n)
$
as
$q_{n+1}-q_n 
= f(q_n)
$
and summing

$\begin{array}\\
q_{n+1}-q_1
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (q_{k+1}-q_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f(q_k)\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^n f(L)\\
&= nf(L)\\
\end{array}
$

which is unbounded,
a contradiction.

Now to get an estimate
for $q_n$
in terms of $f(x)$.

Suppose $q_n = g(n)$
where $g$ is a
reasonably smooth function
(i.e., has at least a first derivative).
Then

$\begin{array}\\
q_{n+1}-q_n
&=g(n+1)-g(n)\\
&=g'(n+c)
\qquad\text{where } 0 \le c \le 1\\
&\approx g'(n)
\qquad\text{this is the big assumption}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$g'(n)
\approx f(q_n)
=f(g(n))
$.

This is the functional equation
that $g$ has to satisfy.

For example,
if $f(x) = \frac{2}{x}$
as in the original problem,
the equation is
$g'(n)
=\frac{2}{g(n)}
$
so
$2 = g(n)g'(n)
=\frac12(g^2(n))'
$.
Integrating,
$4n+c
=g^2(n)$
so
$g(n) = 2\sqrt{n+c_1}
$.
This agrees with my conjecture in my answer
to the original question.

More generally,
if $f(x) = ax^{-b}$
where $a, b > 0$,
the equation is
$g'(n)
=a(g(n))^{-b}
$
or
$a = g'g^b
=\frac1{b+1}(g^{b+1})'
$.

Integrating,
$a(b+1)n+c
=g^{b+1}(n)
$
so
$g(n)
=(a(b+1)n+c)^{1/(b+1)}
$.

As a check,
simplifying with $c=0$,
$g(n) = (a(b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)}$ so

$\begin{array}\\
g(n+1)-g(n)
&=(a(b+1)(n+1)^{1/(b+1)}-(a(b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)}\\
&=(a(b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)}((1+1/n)^{1/(b+1)}-1)\\
&=(a(b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)}(\frac1{(b+1)n}+O(\frac1{n^2}))\\
&=a^{1/(b+1)}((b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)-1}+O(\frac1{n^{2-1/(b+1)}})\\
&=a^{1/(b+1)}((b+1)n)^{-b/(b+1)}+O(\frac1{n^{2-1/(b+1)}})\\
&=\dfrac{a^{1/(b+1)}}{((b+1)n)^{b/(b+1)}}+O(\frac1{n^{1+b/(b+1)}})\\
\text{and}\\
f(g(n))
&=\dfrac{a}{g^b(n)}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{((a(b+1)n)^{1/(b+1)})^b}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{(a(b+1)n)^{b/(b+1)}}\\
&=\dfrac{a^{1/(b+1)}}{((b+1)n)^{b/(b+1)}}\\
\end{array}
$

Another class of functions,
suggested by Will Jagy,
is $f(x) = \frac{a}{b^x}$
where $a > 0, b > 1$,
the equation is
$g'(n)
=\frac{a}{b^{g(n)}}
$
or
$a 
= g'b^g
= g'e^{g\ln(b)}
=\frac1{\ln(b)}(e^{g\ln(b)})'
=\frac1{\ln(b)}(b^g)'
$.

Integrating,
$a\ln(b)n+c
=b^g
$
so
$g(n)\ln(b)
=\ln(a\ln(b)n+c)
$
or
$g(n)
=\dfrac{\ln(a\ln(b)n+c)}{\ln(b)}
$.

If
$a=1, b = e$
as in Will Jagy's example,
$g(n)
=\ln(n+c)
$.

To check,
if $c = 0$,
$g(n) = \dfrac{\ln(a\ln(b)n)}{\ln(b)}$ so

$\begin{array}\\
g(n+1)-g(n)
&=\dfrac{\ln(a\ln(b)(n+1))}{\ln(b)}-\dfrac{\ln(a\ln(b)n)}{\ln(b)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\ln(b)}(\ln(a\ln(b)(n+1))-\ln(a\ln(b)n))\\
&=\dfrac1{\ln(b)}\ln(1+1/n))\\
&=\dfrac1{n\ln(b)}+O(\frac1{n^2})\\
\text{and}\\
f(g(n))
&=\dfrac{a}{b^{g(n)}}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{b^{\frac{\ln(a\ln(b)n)}{\ln(b)}}}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{a\ln(b)n}\\
&=\dfrac1{\ln(b)n}\\
\end{array}
$